# preg_match_all cut catches on accentuated characters

Tags: php, regex, string, utf-8

My objective is to collect every hashtag of a tweet-like string as:

```
$string = "i like to #studyéléctricité in french";
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$string,$hashtags);
```

It captures correctly this hashtags without accents and puts them in the array $hashtags.

But with my string, it will collect only a part of the normal catch, cutting it on the first accentuated character it encounters:

```
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($string));
var_dump($hashtags[0]);
```

it returned

> string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
>
> array (size=1) 0 => string '#study' (length=6)

Solutions tested:

1) the string is in UTF-8 so i tried specific regexes

```
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/u',    $string, $hashtags);
preg_match_all('/#(pL+)/u',    $string, $hashtags);
preg_match_all('/#(p{L}+)/u',  $string, $hashtags);
preg_match_all('/#(\pL+)/u',   $string, $hashtags);
preg_match_all('/#(\p{L}+)/u', $string, $hashtags);
```

These all returned empty arrays.

2) i tried to change the encoding into ISO-8859-15:

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-8');
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$string,$hashtags);
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($string));
var_dump($hashtags[0]);
```

it returned:

> string 'ASCII' (length=5)
>
> array (size=1) 0 => string '#studylctricit' (length=14)

3) i tried also with iconv:

```
$string = iconv($string, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15');
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$string,$hashtags);
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($string));
var_dump($hashtags[0]);
```

it returned:

> string 'ASCII' (length=5)
>
> array (size=1) 0 => string '#study' (length=6)

How may i collect the hashtags with the accentuated characters in this situation?

I thank you by advance for any help or advice you could provide!

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You will need `u` modifier in your regex:

```
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/u',$string,$hashtags);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can capture these letters with `\p{L}+` regex and `u` option:

```
$string = "i like to #studyéléctricité in french";
preg_match_all('/#(\p{L}+)/u',$string,$hashtags);
print_r($hashtags);
```

Here is a [working sample program](http://goo.gl/60SmQC).

Output:

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [0] => Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            [0] => #studyéléctricité                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    [1] => Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            [0] => studyéléctricité                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

)
```